# How can I make curved form text inputs in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a project to create a website designed in PhotoShop. I want to create a to textbox in HTML and CSS which looks like this:

[image: Image that I want to convert]

As you can see, there is no problem with the background or fonts; the problem is the textbox. How can I create textboxes with these curves?

Comment: Are you asking how to get that shape?

Comment: Try this and add borders for the same. Although the input area will still be rectangular in this case. Will this be okay ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  background: #444;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff
}

input {
  border-radius: 0 2em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

textarea {
  border-radius: 0 4em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea></textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get the shape in your image. You will need to learn a bit about `border-radius`.

The following is an example:

```css
div#test {
  border: thin solid #666;
  width: 8em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 0 2em 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">&nbsp;</div>
```

The `border-radius` property is responsible for rounding corners. It can be very sophisticated, but the simple one here will do the job. You will just need to adjust some of the values.

The four values in the `border-radius` property represent the radius of the individual borders, *clockwise* from the *top-left* corner.